# CursorAdapter and OnItemClickListener

Tags: android

I have read other topics and I still have problem. `setOnItemClickListener` should be in Adapter class like below or in "MainActivity" class?
If is in Adapter class It can't do right reference to layout.
Error logcat:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void     
 android.widget.ListView.setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

ListAdapter.java

```
public class ListAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
public ListAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
    super(context, cursor, 0);
}
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.items, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
    // Find fields to populate in inflated template
    TextView txt1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TitleLabel);
    TextView txt2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.SecondLabel);
    TextView txt3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ThirdLabel);
    // Extract properties from cursor
    String name = cursor.getString(1);


    txt1.setText(name);

    ListView listview = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                                final int position, final long id) {
           final String itemId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            Log.i("Activity", "Cursor: " + cursor + " + " + position + " + id " + id + " ITEMID: " + itemId);
            // final String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            view.animate().setDuration(500).alpha(0)
                    .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                          // it was for SimpleCursorAdapter
                            listview.remove(item);
                            helper.deleteitem(id+1);
                          helper.deleteItemByName(item);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            view.setAlpha(1);

                        }
                    });*/
        }

    });
}
}
```

Comment: why you have a ListView as part of the item ? `listview.setOnItemClickListener` should be in your Activity

Comment: Inside Activity class I can't refer to cursor

Comment: of course you can, why do you think you can't?

Comment: because I don't know how do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to have setOnItemClickListener in oyur MainActivity but if you wish to use in your Adapter class then use setOnclickListener method of **parent lauout** of R.layout.items

Because in bindView each items are treated as single item.

**Edited**

Add id in Relative layout

```
android:id="@+id/myRelativelayout"
```

In Adatpter class

```
  RelativeLayout rl =(RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.myRelativelayout);
```

implement r1.setOnClickListener and add your code.

Comment: In Activity: `Cannot resolve cursor` in : cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));

Comment: If you are facing other issue then have onClick (for parent layout)in Adapter class.

Comment: If you are not getting then post code of R.layout.items

Comment: Ok. It's working but how I can get position id and example specific name item from ListView? I think this solution is well for button not for ListView.

Comment: You can get position by int pos = view.getPosition(); and once you have position you can get items as well.

Comment: this return still the same number. Maybe final int position = getListView();.getPositionForView(arg0); ?

Answer (score 0):

## items.xml layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/postThumb"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TitleLabel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/postThumb"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/postThumb"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Lorem Ipsum 1 line"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:ellipsize="end"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/SecondLabel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/postThumb"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ThirdLabel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/postThumb"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/postThumb"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="11dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```